# Google Cloud Speech use custom vocabulary

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I would like to use Google Cloud Speech for recognizing speech in a specific domain (healthcare). I know it already allows to add additional words to the vocabulary of the recognizer (word hints), but this must be done at each API call. Do you know if it can be done separately, by creating a priori your own custom vocabulary?

Comment: I'd like to know if this is doable too - did you learn anything? -- im also afraid this is a bit OT for StackOverflow

Comment: You can use phrase hints like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009619/google-cloud-speech-api-word-hints, but overall it is better to use more flexible speech recognition system which allows vocabulary training.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, Google Cloud Speech only allows users to specify phrase hints via [`speechContexts`](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/speech-adaptation) in each API call. Some other ASRs such as Microsoft ASR do allow users to train their own language model.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [CustomClass](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1p1beta1/projects.locations.customClasses), it may help you. Create your own class and use it whatever you want