# How to get Google Cloud Speech (voice-to-text) to recognize letters and sounds

Tags: google-cloud-speech

Is there a way to get the [Google Cloud Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/) to recognize letters and letter sounds?

As an example use case, if I wanted to build a spelling game where a voice would say, "Spell restaurant" and the recognizer would listen for each letter and recognize them as they come through.

Similarly, is there a way to identify specific letter sounds like: "oo", "ew", "k" (as in cat) or "s" (as in circle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to already do a reasonable job at least in some cases.  E.g., when I spell out "cee ay tee" it recognizes "c a t".  It is also possible to provide "word hints" as described in this post:

[Google Cloud Speech API word Hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009619/google-cloud-speech-api-word-hints)

Supplying a list of single-letter "words" as hints, i.e.

```
phrases = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ... ]
```

appears to give improved results in this area.