# How to add custom terms to OpenAI's Whisper STT/ASR?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, openai-whisper

I have some domain specific jargon I would like Whisper to be able recognize.  Is there a way, like Azure's custom speech, or Google's ASR, to add new terms to the system's language model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way, like Azure's custom speech, or Google's ASR, to add new terms to the system's language model?

Currently, the two possible
options are [hint phrases](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73833916/395857) and [fine-tuning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73841388/395857).